# for a survey conducted in 3 countries, how to examine the equivalence of factor structure by country?

Tags: factor-analysis, survey

We conducted a survey in 3 countries, and we want to run factor analysis (EFA) to identify latent factors. With the combined data sets, we can run EFA to develop factors. 
But to examine the equivalence of factor structure by country, what shall I do? shall I do 3 different EFA using 3 subsets, each from one single country?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a Procrustes rotation to a target matrix to get descriptor of the similarity of the three solutions.

A better solution is to move to a multiple group confirmatory factor analysis approach, which lets you directly test the equivalence of the three factor solutions.

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy. I will google how to do it. If you can explain a little bit here how to do it, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at Vandenberg & Lance (2000) for a nice conceptual review of the process of evaluating measurement invariance (what Jeremy is encouraging you to do in CFA). In terms of implementing it yourself for your research, I would look at the lavaan and semTools packages for R, which can be used with relative ease to fit measurement invariance models (you can easily google their documentation, and the lavaan package has a nice website with easy-to-follow tutorials)